# Laravel 5.3 Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

bom dia!
Segui o que está dito neste tutorial para preencher valores em uma view:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/retrieve_records.htm

E fiz o mesmo esquema no meu controller:

```
public function select_cursos_disciplinas()
{
    $cursos = DB::table('select * from cursos');
    $disciplinas = DB::table('select * from disciplinas');
    return view('cadastros.disciplinas_curso', ['cursos' => $cursos, 'disciplinas' => $disciplinas]);
}
```

Na minha view está assim:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected> --- </option>    
    @if ($cursos)
        @foreach ($cursos as $curso)
            <option> {{ $curso->nome }} </option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</select>
```

Entretanto, está dando o erro "Trying to get property of non-object". Já pesquisei mas não achei a solução para o que preciso, pois a solução era para apenas um valor, mas no meu caso quero vários valores mesmo.

O que eu deveria fazer para que meu select seja preenchido?
Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acontece que seu método não está carregando os dados para o objeto. Para isso você precisa aplicar o método `get()` ao final do método `table`.

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public function select_cursos_disciplinas()
{
    $cursos = DB::table('select * from cursos')->get();
    $disciplinas = DB::table('select * from disciplinas')->get();
    return view('cadastros.disciplinas_curso')
           ->with('cursos', $cursos)
           ->with('disciplinas', $disciplinas);
}
```

Seu `foreach` na view está certo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Gumball. Mas ainda deu o mesmo erro :/. Estou lendo o log aqui e parece que esse DB retorna um objeto do tipo stdClass. Será que tem algo a ver?

Comment: Haaa, verdade. Coloca um `->get()` no fim do método. Vou editar meu código.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic você poderia talvez dar um tempo hábil para dar esses tipos de comentários. Eu já estava com isso em mente e quando tiver um tempo edito a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou. Entretanto, tive que mudar a string dentro do table só para o nome da tabela, porque senão dava erro. Mas já deu um pontapé para a solução.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que seja melhor usar o `Query Builder` do `Eloquent`.
Tente da seguinte forma.

```
public function select_cursos_disciplinas()
{
    $curso = new Curso();
    $cursos = $curso->all();

    $disciplina = new Disciplina();
    $disciplinas = $disciplina->all();

    return view('cadastros.disciplinas_curso', 
        [
            'cursos' => $cursos, 
            'disciplinas' => $disciplinas
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Gostaria de saber porquê é melhor.

Comment: @Gumball em minha opinião fica menos verboso, mais simples de entender, e diminui problemas como sql inject, mas é minha opinião. O Eloquent é muito bom e os recursos dele são ótimos.

Comment: @Gumball ele também diminui a escrita de sql nativo dentro do método, por isso fica menos verboso e diminui o risco de injeção de sql.

Comment: Entendi. É que eu não costumo usar nem Query Builder e nem Fluent. Sempre Eloquent.

Comment: O Query Builder é do Eloquent ^^, recomendo dar uma olhada, ele da uma boa agilizada no desenvolvimento, sem escrever queries nativas :), inclusive usando dentro das entidades.


https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations
/-----
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries

Comment: Sim. Eu uso esses métodos.