# Erro - Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5.3

Mudei o meu banco de produção ,para  local a base de produção retorna os objetos
já a minha base de dados local aparece esta mensagem  [image: Trying to get property of non-object]

Meu projetoController

```
/**
* Lista todos os projetos ativos
* @access public
* @param NULL
* @return arrProjetos para a view('pmo.projetos')
*/
public function listarProjetos() {
    //DB::enableQueryLog();

    $arrProjetos = Projetos::all();
    $arrProjetosPendentes = array();
    $arrProjetosInativos = array();
    $intIndex = 0;

    foreach ($arrProjetos as $objProjeto) {
        $objDataConclusaoLimite = new DateTime($objProjeto->data_conclusao_realizada);
        $objDataConclusaoLimite->add(new DateInterval('P12D')); // Inserindo + 7 dias a data de conclusão
        $objDataAtual = new DateTime(); // Pegando a data atual

        // Seprando projetos com status 4 (Excluidos)
        if ($objProjeto->status == self::Excluido) {
            array_push($arrProjetosInativos, $arrProjetos[$intIndex]);
            unset($arrProjetos[$intIndex]);
        }
        // Seprando projetos pendentes
        elseif ($objProjeto->status == self::Pendente) {
            array_push($arrProjetosPendentes, $arrProjetos[$intIndex]);
            unset($arrProjetos[$intIndex]);
        }
        // Mudando status de projetos concluidos a mais de 7 dias
        elseif ($objDataConclusaoLimite < $objDataAtual) {
            $objProjeto->status = self::Excluido;
            $objProjeto->save();
        }
        $intIndex++;


/**
* Lista todos os projetos
* @access public
* @param NULL
* @return Array $arrProjetos para a view('pmo.projetos')
*/
public function listarTodos() {
    $arrProjetos = Projetos::all();

    foreach($arrProjetos as $objProjeto) {
        $objDono = Stakeholders::find($objProjeto->dono);
        $objProjeto->dono = $objDono->nome;
    }

    return view('pmo.admin.projetos', compact('arrProjetos'));
}
```

}

Tentei fazer usando este post  [Trying to get property of non-object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163015/laravel-5-3-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object)
  mesmo assim nada ,  a questão é com as mesmas informaçoes só que local ,não estar retornando dados do objeto . O banco de dados é o SQL Server 2014
   Projeto feito em Laravel 5.3
  Meus models : estão separados em

Área :

```
 class Area extends Model{
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'area';
protected $IntId = 'id';
protected $fillable = ['nome'];
 }
```

Comentário :

```
class Comentario extends Model{

public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'comentarios';
protected $IntId = 'id';
protected $IntIdProjeto = 'id_projeto';
protected $IntIdStakeholder = 'id_stakeholder';
protected $strComentario = 'comentario';
protected $strData = 'data_publicado';
protected $boolExcluido = 'excluido';

public function projetos() {
    return $this->belongsToOne('App\Models\Projetos', 'projeto', 'id', 'id_projeto');
}

public function stakeholders() {
    return $this->belongsToone('App\Models\Stakeholders', 'stakeholders', 'id', 'id_stakeholder');
}

/*public function roles() {
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Projetos','projeto_stakeholders','id_projeto','id_stakeholder')
```

}*/
}

Projetos :

```
class Projetos extends Model{
public $timestamps = false;

protected $table = 'projetos';
protected $IntId = 'id';
protected $fillable = array('nome', 'area', 'data_criacao', 'data_conclusao_prevista', 
'status', 'porcentagem', 'codigo', 'dono', 'descricao');//campos da tabela
protected $strDataUltimaAtualizacao = 'data_ultima_atualizacao';
protected $strArquivo = 'arquivo';
protected $strDescricao = 'descricao';
protected $strDataArquivoAtualizacao = 'data_arquivo_atualizacao';

public function areas() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Area', 'id', 'area');
 }

public function stakeholders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Stakeholders', 'projeto_stakeholders', 'id_projeto', 'id_stakeholder');
}

public function comentario() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comentario', 'id_projeto', 'id');
}

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Projetos', 
'projeto_stakeholders', 'id_projeto', 'id_stakeholder');

}
```

Responsável :

```
class Responsavel extends Model{
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'responsavel';
protected $IntId = 'id';
protected $fillable = array('login', 'nome', 'email');    

public function projetos() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Projetos');
}
```

}
    Stakeholders

```
class Stakeholders extends Model{
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'stakeholders';
protected $IntId = 'id';
protected $fillable = array('login', 'nome', 'email');
protected $boolAdmin = 'admin';
protected $boolBoss = 'boss';
protected $strSenha = 'senha';
protected $strTokenResetarSenha = 'token_resetar_senha';

public function projetos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Projetos', 'projeto_stakeholders', 'id_projeto', 'id_stakeholder');
}

public function comentario() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comentario', 'id_stakeholder', 'id');
}

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Projetos', 'projeto_stakeholders', 'id_projeto', 'id_stakeholder');
}
```

Estes são os meus modelos do sistema

Comment: Posta o Código do ProjetosControlador completo pra dar uma olhada? Acho que só copiou as funções ali no enunciado..

Comment: `$arrProjetos = Projetos::all()->get();` tentei fazer assim e não funciona.. será que é erro porque a base de dados que criei ta errada ?

Comment: Tem bastante código, será que isso tudo é necessário, qual a finalidade do seu código? você fez a relação dos Models corretamente? eu vi muita coisa que pode ser suprimida, mas, é dificil responder por causa da sua regra ou contexto ...

Comment: A finalidade é um determinado usuario ,poder visualizar todos os projetos que existem no sistema(banco de dados)

Comment: Entendi, mas, você acha que precisa fazer isso? vamos lá como estão seus models? como é sua tabela? tem com postar? porque o erro é outro o problema é que se você relacionar tudo certo não precisa escrever tanto for!

Comment: Porque tem `protected $strDataUltimaAtualizacao = 'data_ultima_atualizacao';`????

Comment: é quando é atualizado algum projeto de algum stakeholder , ele sempre pega a data da última atualização

Comment: Olha Ricardo eu realmente estou mais na duvida que você, porque, eu nunca vi ninguém fazer assim ... !!! desculpa! vamos ver se alguém pode te ajudar, acho que não precisa mas,  ... !

Comment: Estou com dificuldades de criar as migrations.. o projeto não tinha a pasta migration, criei ela manualmente e quando tento criar a migration relacionada ao meu objeto este erro aparece `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "name".` quero criar o banco do zero pra subir este projeto já criado...